# AWS: can I enable CloudWatch "centralized monitoring account" using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I have different accounts in AWS.
Now I would like to use CloudWatch to centralized monitoring account, but I don't found a solution to configure "Monitoring account configuration" using Terraform:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably related to enabling AWS Organizations. Are your accounts in an organization?

Comment: Yes, they are in an organization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the Observability Access Manager resources:

1. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/oam_sink
2. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/oam_link

Based on the AWS documentation for [sink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/OAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSink.html) and [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/OAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLink.html), you should create the sink in the monitoring account and links in all the member accounts.

EDIT: As per the comments, the [sink policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/oam_sink_policy) resource is also required.

Comment: it's works, I added the resource aws_oam_sink_policy too.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't entirely sure if that's needed, I will update my answer with that link as well.